# ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError - Simple blog and rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, rails-models

I am trying to learn the new changes in rails 4 so started with a blog . Ran a scaffold with a title and body , everything went well until i clicked on save and i was greeted with the error ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError . I know i need to make some changes in controller , but i read the blogs and made changes for the same .

Following is my controller

```
class BlogpostsController < InheritedResources::Base
  def create
     Blogpost.create(blogpost_params)
  end

  private
  def blogpost_params
    params.require(:blogpost).permit(:body,:title)
  end
end
```

Please do point me the right way as i am still new to rails 4 and also any tutorials defining the same would also be helpful . Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have controller code in a model class , that's what wrong. The create action and the strong parameters should be defined in your blog_posts controller. The code itself seems fine.

Comment: I had written it by mistake , changed it . Please check

Comment: Good to hear, could you accept my answer? P.s. It would be nice to keep the wrong example in your question, so that others making the same mistake know what went wrong.